# A 'too many values to unpack' error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

```
import pylab as pl

data = """AP 10
AA 20
AB 30
BB 40
BC 40
CC 30
CD 20
DD 10"""

grades = []
number = []

for line in data.split("/n"):
     x, y = line.split()
     grades.append(x)
     number.append(int(y))       
fig = pl.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.bar(grades,number)
p.show()
```

This is my code, i wish to make a bar graph, from the data.
Initially when I run my code, I was getting an indentation error, in line 17, after adding a space to all the entire for block, I started getting this 'too many values to unpack error', in line 16.
I am new to python, and I don't know how to proceed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `for-loop` is splitting at the wrong token (`/n`) instead of `\n`.

But when you only want to split the newlines there actually is a `splitlines()`-method on strings that does just that: you should actually use this method, because it will handle different newline delimiters between *nix and Windows as well (*nix systems typically denote newlines via `\r\n`, whereas Windows uses `\n` and the old Mac OS uses `\r`: check the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) for more information)

Your error occurs on the next line: due to the fact that the string was not split into lines your whole string will now be split on the whitespace, which will produces many more values than the 2 you try to assign to a tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Er, now I am getting an error "cannot convert 'float' object to str implicitly".
But is there any float object? Why such an error?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I guess the error is from `matplotlib`: the `bar` function (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) requires two arguments: - left: the x-coordinates of the left side (I guess these need to be a float not a str). - right: the heights of the bar. So you probably need to use a list denoting the bar width instead of the labels as first argument. To set the labels you probably could use the `xticks` function in matplotlib - there is an exentsive example in the matplotlib-docs. See if that helps or just ask away again :)

Comment: Yes, I read the error properly, it is due to the matplotlib function..
So I changed grades to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], and then used the xticks function, and now its done properly :)
Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 4):

You have a line that does *not* have two items on it:

```
 x, y = line.split()
```

did not split to two elements and that throws the error. Most likely because you are not splitting your `data` variable properly and have the whole text as *one* long text. `/n` does not occur in your `data` data.

Use `.splitlines()` instead:

```
for line in data.splitlines():
     x, y = line.split()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in data.split("/n")
```

should be

```
for line in data.split("\n")
```

or even better:

```
for line in data.splitlines()
```

Comment: this is one of those time where a second pair of eyes is invaluable!

Answer (score 1):

For a fun alternative, rather than using the `splitlines` method as proposed by others, You could also use a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object here:

```
>>> data = """AP 10
... AA 20
... AB 30
... BB 40
... BC 40
... CC 30
... CD 20
... DD 10"""
>>> import cStringIO as StringIO
>>> filelike = StringIO.StringIO(data)
>>> for line in filelike:
...     print line.split()
... 
['AP', '10']
['AA', '20']
['AB', '30']
['BB', '40']
['BC', '40']
['CC', '30']
['CD', '20']
['DD', '10']
```